# How to collect data with a KafkaConsumer and expose it with Flask

Tags: python, flask, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a `KafkaConsumer` code (in python) that looks something like:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(...)

all_messages = []
for message in consumer:
    all_messages.append(message)
```

I would like to know how I could combine this with a trivial `Flask` server code that looks something like:

```
@app.route("/get_all_messages",  methods=['GET'])
def get_all_messages():
    return jsonify(all_messages)
```

To my understanding this isn't straightforward, as both the `KafkaConsumer` loop and the `Flask` implementation do not release the thread they run on.

Is there a way to solve this, other than separating the implementation to two services? That way, the `KafkaConsumer` could `POST` the data to the `Flask` http server, which will also have the `GET` API above.

Comment: Can't you run the Kafka consumer in a separate thread? Have it deliver messages into a `Queue` that you read in the flask endpoint.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://github.com/aiven/karapace

Comment: Thanks @larsks. I guess your solution makes sense. I was unnecessarily hoping for a method that would abstract the need of explicit thread management. Especially since I have no knowledge (at the moment) on how Flask manages its internals, and what side effects I might be missing. If you would care to restructure as an answer I would accept it. Or I can write the code and then answer myself with snippets. :)

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. That does seem like it could help with my task, and do a lot more. Perhaps too much more, since I think that at least as the task is defined here (and until I need something more holistic), it would be a bit of an overkill. I guess a solution that simply puts the consumer within its own thread can achieve this with just a couple more lines of code. Will get back to karapace when the time is right.